# FlashVars & AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashvars

So im trying to gain access to flash vars but i kept getting this error:

> Line 27   1180: Call to a possibly undefined method LoaderInfo.

I have tried putting the below code in and outside of my class but it seems from what i have gathered that it thinks 'LoaderInfo' is another function which it is not.

```
public function getFlashVars():Object {
    var paramList:Object = LoaderInfo( this.root.loaderInfo ).parameters;
    var myParam:String = paramList["myParam"];
    return myParam;
}
```

How do i get around this?

Eli

Comment: @MartyWallace Yes i know that, but i should not still be getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the import for `flash.display.LoaderInfo`.

But you can probably just as well omit the type cast:

`this.root.loaderInfo.parameters;`

Answer (score 0):

From the likes of your function name & return type, it seems you are rather tryiing to implement this:

```
function getFlashVars():Object{

    return root.loaderInfo.parameters;
}
```

Besides this is already a static object for you. You don't really need a function to fetch these parameters.

At least not the one as above. You may fetch them as:

```
root.loaderInfo.parameters.myParam1
root.loaderInfo.parameters.myParam2
root.loaderInfo.parameters.myParam3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an elegant way to work with flashvars, you could use [FlashVars class](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/temple/data/flashvars/FlashVars.html) from [the temple library](http://code.google.com/p/templelibrary/). This class is a wrapper around the flashvars, so they can be accessed at places where there is no Stage.

You have the possibility to set a default and a class-type for each flashvar individually. In combination with a FlashVarNames enum class you know which flashvars are used in the application.

You should instantiate/configure the FlashVars once in your main file.

```
package
{
    import temple.data.flashvars.FlashVars;

    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class FlashVarsExample extends DocumentClassExample 
    {
        private static const _LANGUAGE:String = 'language';
        private static const _VERSION:String = 'version';
        private static const _IS_DEMO:String = 'is_demo';

        public function FlashVarsExample()
        {
            FlashVars.initialize(this.loaderInfo.parameters);

            FlashVars.configureVar(_LANGUAGE, 'nl', String);
            FlashVars.configureVar(_VERSION, 1, int);
            FlashVars.configureVar(_IS_DEMO, true, Boolean);

            var txt:TextField = new TextField();
            txt.width = 550;
            txt.height = 400;
            this.addChild(txt);

            trace('FlashVars.getValue(_LANGUAGE) : ' + FlashVars.getValue(_LANGUAGE) + "\n");
            trace('FlashVars.getValue(_VERSION) : ' + FlashVars.getValue(_VERSION) + "\n");
            trace('FlashVars.getValue(_IS_DEMO) : ' + FlashVars.getValue(_IS_DEMO) + "\n");
            trace(FlashVars.dump());
        }
    }
}
```